# How to use <select> in vee-validate?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I wasnt able to use my form   inside vee-validate.

As in documentation  , It says use `<Field />` but I cant use in Select form.
How can i build this thank you.

```
<Form @submit="submit">
   <Field name="email" type="email">
    <div class="form-floating">
     //cant get idea to convert select to Field
        <select class="form-select" >
            <option selected>Select your category</option>
            <option value="a">a</option>
            <option value="c">b-</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</Form>
```

How can i use ?
Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may replace `type="email"` by `as="select"`

```
<Field name="field" as="select">
  <option value="">Select value</option>
  <option value="..">...</option>
</Field>
```

You can read more here: https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/api/field

Comment: In my case I'm using the vuestic components (https://vuestic.dev/) how can I use and validate the va-select component?